# Showing a high resolution image in WP8?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my Windows phone 8 app, I am binding web-URL to Image control.

I have two pages, on first page i am binding a low resolution image(I Have web-URL of multiple resolutions). On next page I have to show the same Image in full screen mode so I am binding high resolution image URL. But it takes some time to load.

Then I tried to bind the same low resolution image which I have on previous page to this Full screen Image Control  and then binding the high resolution image.

So my problem is here, when I am adding a low res image, its getting displayed and then I am binding a high res image. so for some time no image is appear.

Please suggest, How can i show the continuous image, Image should not be disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [MultiScaleImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control or wait until your High-Res image completes downloading, then re-bind your control.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using two `Image` solution. Place your lo-res image into visible `Image` control and place your hi-res image into hidden `Image` control. Once hi-res image is loaded you can hide lo-res image and show hires one. For extra smooth user experience you can use animations to cross-fade images.

Subscribe to [`ImageOpened`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imageopened.aspx) event so you know then image is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Denis. But how I will came to know that high resolution image is loaded, because I have web URLs of images.

Comment: you can listen to ImageOpened event on Image control.